# How to Combine GROUP CONCAT with COUNT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that can get result from multiple tables:

**Item Category**

| ic_id | ic_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PC |
| 2 | Laptop |
| 3 | Printer |
| 4 | Scanner |

**Items**

| i_id | i_category | i_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Dell Optiplex |
| 2 | 2 | HP Probook 450 |
| 3 | 2 | HP Probook650 |
| 4 | 3 | HP Laserjet 402dn |
| 5 | 1 | Dell MT3030 |

**Item Sale**

| is_id | is_date | is_customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-03-2021 | John |
| 2 | 16-03-2022 | Jimmy |
| 3 | 18-03-2023 | Mark |

**Item Sale Detail**

| isd_id | isd_sale_id | isd_item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |

Is it possible to get combined result of GROUP CONCAT with COUNT in 1 query? Please guide me to write the query to get the desired result, I want the query result as shown below, Thanks:

**Desired Result**

| is_id | is_date | is_customer | items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-03-2021 | John | Laptop: 3 |
| 2 | 16-03-2022 | Jimmy | Printer: 1 |
| 3 | 18-03-2023 | Mark | PC:2 , Printer: 1 |

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this is just `join` but with two levels of aggregation:

```
select its.*, ic.categories
from item_sale its join
     (select isd.isd_sale_id,
             group_concat(ic_name, ':', cnt order by cnt desc) as categories
      from (select isd.isd_sale_id, ic.ic_name, count(*) as cnt
            from item_sale_detail isd join
                 items i
                 on isd.isd_item = i.i_id join
                 item_category ic
                 on i.i_category = ic.ic_id
            group by isd.isd_sale_id, ic.ic_name
           ) ic
      group by isd.isd_sale_id
     ) ic
     on i.is_id = ic.isd_sale_id;
```